# "laser_geometry.h" cannot be used

Tags: ros, laser-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why I got an error when I use #include "laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h" or with (<>). Is this one deprecated in Electric. Or any path that I can use in Electric..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11854/%22laser_geometry.h%22-cannot-be-used/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to add the laser_geometry package as a dependency to the manifest.xml of your own package:

```
  <depend package="laser_geometry"/>
```

The #include as stated by you should then work (provided laser_geometry can be found in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-08**:
@dornhege: I also assume that way..just to cross check with you all..thanks anyway..

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-08**:
It's probably already a dependency of another package you use.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-08**:
Thanks a lot..I just wonder for some packages i even don't need to add it in manifest file like geometry_msgs package that i use, it just works..